# do I have to download a full 800-900 MB setup or only a smaller specific upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

When the TT 14.04 is released, on upgrading from SS 13.10, do I have to download a full 800-900 MB setup or only a smaller specific upgrade? I'm only asking this out of curiousity anyway, but bandwidth back here in my country is pretty limited so better to know beforehand.

Comment: no, i mean i have the full version of 13.10
& now i want to upgrade to full version of 14.04, with all default applications & their updates
will that take 800-900MB (as in a fresh new download of 14.04) or smaller?

Comment: oh indeed, i see
so a fresh installation is better & it will have no caveats at all... Nice, i'll precisely do that
thanks for enhancing my knowledge, dude

Comment: Note that you can upgrade also with the Live 14.04 installer. It has an option to upgrade without deleting user data. I upgraded my 13.10 with that.

Comment: hey, hang on
wasn't 14.04 scheduled for April 17th release? Or are you talking about the final beta?

Comment: I used some daily image a couple of weeks ago :) It has been stable enough for daily use already.

Comment: Let me convert these comments to an answer. Then you can accept that as correct, and that will help others.

Comment: @user205301 the upgrade option is highly discouraged, HIGLHY, I upgraded my system that way and everything was gone, I was left with broken packages, and had to reinstall everything

Comment: Well, I rescued my system with the live upgrade option, because do-release-upgrade just made my system unbootable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to say. The upgrade process will calculate how much needs to be downloaded.

It may be larger, if you have installed some application *X* (where *X* is any application) that was at **version n** in the Saucy repository and is at **version n+1** in the Trusty repository, then an upgrade will download that as well. If you do a fresh install, you will need to download that application X separately and install it again.

It may be smaller, if you uninstall some of the default applications in Ubuntu 13.10 that you don't need, such as *Mahjong* etc. Those applications won't be upgraded to the newer versions that will come with 14.04. [There are some downsides to upgrade.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17367/upgrade-vs-clean-install)

As @user205301 has pointed out. You can also upgrade from the LiveDVD/USB. This option will keep your `/home` folder and all the data in it while removing some (if not all) of the user installed applications *X*.

Hope this helps

Comment: yeah, it really helped me out very much
thanks for your thoroughly comprehensive explanation

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to beta a few days ago. It took me 1 GB of data compared to 932 MB iso and 5 hours to be upgraded. It is definitely slower than fresh install. You should do upgrade only when you have tons of programs which otherwise would need re-install. By the way, a friendly suggestion. Create a separate /home partition so that if you do fresh installs, you can keep all your data without wiping it away.

Comment: i see... Well, i'll do a fresh install of 14.04 then...
Thanks for the suggestion & taking the time to help me out :)